# Properties of meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

In the book Sadri Hassani for mathematical physics, the author derives the following result:-
[image: ro]

I am not sure how the conclusion that the term $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is bounded follows. For instance, I can take $f(z) = e^{z^2}$ and the term becomes $2z$, which is clearly unbounded. Is there a problem in the proof or am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: Your counterexample is correct. Perhaps there are additional conditions on $g$ which you have not shown?

Comment: Yes, perhaps g is assumed bounded?

Comment: Bounded entire functions  are constants. I think the book is has  lots of mistakes unless bounded  for all $z$ is replaced by locally bounded. @Paul

Comment: @MartinR I couldn't find any additional assumptions. This discussion follows directly after explaining a version of Mittag-Leffler expansion. The full page is shown here:- ibb.co/G97S02f